# Aggregating against two fields returns nulls for one of them

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got an index with a lot of records with many fields, including "cacheName" & "cache_ip".  Each unique value of "cacheName" has 1 or more records with 1 or more values of corresponding "cache_ip".  Each record has a unique 'ts' (timestamp) field as well. For example:

```
{
"cacheName": "c001.abc001.xyz",
"cache_ip": "1.1.1.0",
},
{
"cacheName": "c001.abc001.xyz",
"cache_ip": "1.1.2.0",
},
{
"cacheName": "c002.efg001.mno",
"cache_ip": "1.1.9.1",
},
{
"cacheName": "c002.efg001.mno",
"cache_ip": "1.1.9.1",
},
```

I'm trying to craft a search that will return, at most, each unique 'cacheName' & 'cache_ip' record.  For the above example, I would get back a total of 3 hits ("cacheName"="c002.efg001.mno" would only be returned once, since it only has one unique permutation).

This is the closest that I've come, but it always returns a Null value for "cache_ip" instead of the actual value (there are no null values in the actual data):

```
{ 
 "size": 0, 'sort': [{'ts': {'order': 'desc'}}], 
 "query": { 
             "bool": { 
                 "must": [ 
                     {"match_all": {}}, 
                     {"range": {'ts': {'gte': '20200818T010100Z', 'format': 'basic_date_time_no_millis'}}}, 
                 ] 
             } 
         }, 
 "aggs": { 
             "cacheName": { 
                 "terms": { 
                     "field": "cacheName", 
                     "size": 10000, "order": {"_key": "desc"}, 
                     }, 
                 "aggs": { 
                     "cache_ip": {"terms": {"field": "cache_ip"}}, 
                     }, 
              }, 
       }, 
}
```

I'd appreciate any insight, as I'm pulling my hair out trying to make this work.

thanks!

Comment: Do you get any results when running this query: `GET your-index/_search?q=NOT(_exists_:cache_ip)`

Comment: No, zero records returned from that search.

Comment: What is the mapping type of `cache_ip`?

Comment: Mapping is string for that field

Comment: `text` or `keyword`?

Comment: text is what is set

Comment: Ok, that's the problem then. It would need to be `keyword` or `ip`

Comment: So you're suggesting that if I keep the exact search that I posted originally, but change the mapping type to either keyword or ip, that will fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want to is use scripting to create all the permutations and you wouldn't need the second `terms` sub-aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "ts": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "ts": {
              "gte": "20200818T010100Z",
              "format": "basic_date_time_no_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "cacheName": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "[doc.cache_name.value ?: 'no.name', doc.cache_ip.value ?: 'no.ip'].join('-')"
        },
        "size": 10000,
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, scripting is disabled on my server, so this will not be feasible.  Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Yes, you need to reindex your data by adding a new field that contains the concatenation of the two fields, basically what the script does dynamically

Comment: Ok, that's going to be challenging to pull off, as I'm working within very strict limits on fields and indices.  Thanks though.

Comment: No, it will take a lot of time to make these changes.  Likely months.